# Any way to map WebDAV with SSL as network drive in Windows XP?

Tags: ssl, webdav, network-share

I'm trying to map WebDAV with SSL as a network drive in Windows XP. (I've been at this for several hours) I can read the share just fine using a browser and with Network Places, but it refuses to mount as a network drive.

I've tried it using the Windows explorer interface and net use.

Net use with the \\server@ssl:443\webdav method gives System error 53. https://server/webdav gives error 67.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it working on Windows Server 2008 R2.

1. The Web site is pointed at C:\inetpub\webDAV.
2. Authentication used is Windows Integrated
3. WebDAV is Authorized to for All Users, with Read, Write permission.
4. Command I use is "net use \win-2k8wss1@ssl:443"

Error message: 53 means "The network path was not found."
Error message: 67 means "The network name cannot be found."

Please verify if the command you are using is correct.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it cannot be done with Windows out-of-the-box. I believe you will have to either:

- Settle for a different sharing protocol. Either SMB/Samba/CIFS or whatever you call it (possibly through a VPN), or maybe sshfs through Dokan.
- Splurge for a non-free component that can do that, which might not exist. FTP ones do exist, though
- Do it indirectly, using a Linux or Mac box- both are able to mount WebDAV as a fs, and re-export it through Samba or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

WebDAV through XP has a few gotchas. We're having to deploy a large number of volumes via WebDAV and have a lot of XP clients. It can work, but it takes planning.

- WebDAV on XP can not support root-level folders. It has to be a sub folder. For instance, https://server.domain.org/ will not work at all, but https://server.domain.org/username/ will work.
- WebDAV is dependent upon SSL certs. The SSL has to fully pass validation for it to work at all. The errors reported by the client do not always mention SSL, so check for this.
- You don't do WebDAV maps the way you do regular old SMB mounts. You're adding a new network place, not a drive mapping.

[image: Select "Sign up for online storage or connect to a network server"]
<sub>(source: [sysadmin1138.net](http://sysadmin1138.net/images/xp-webdav.png))</sub>

You click on the link named "Sign up for online storage or connect to a network server", and then go through a few more dialog screens. The new Network Place will be visible under Network Places under Windows Explorer.

Comment: I think it must be the certificate not being "correct." I just find it really odd that I can make a Network Place, but not map the drive (like Samba). If I try to map the Network Place as a drive, the "OK" button is disabled.

Comment: That's because WebDAV is not a full system mount, it doesn't support all the semantics Windows needs for drive-letter access. Samba can provide things like record locks within a file, but WebDAV can't. MS did this on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Drive mounting tool on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 does not support SSL as well as it does not work with any ports other than 80.

On XP and 2003 it also does not support neither Basic nor Digest, you have to use Integrated Windows Authentication only.

Here is the full description: http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/map_drive

You will have to use drive mounting tool on Windows Vista, Windows 7 or any third-party WebDAV client like this one: http://www.webdavsystem.com/mapdrive

Comment: Heads up: this is non-free and requires registration for an evaluation version.